# VisualForce Email template giving error

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I want to right one condition in my email template something like (((Country == 'xyz' && RT != 'abc') || Country != 'xyz') && (credit!=null || Debit!=null)) in my visualforce email template

I'm writing it as

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!AND(OR(AND(relatedTo.country == 'xyz',relatedto.RT != ‘abc’),relatedTo.country != 'xyz'),OR(relatedTo.credit !=null, relatedTo.debit !=null))}">
```

But I'm getting Syntax error. Can somebody please tell what im doing wrong.

Comment: your quotations around `relatedto.RT != ‘abc’` looks different

Comment: oh Yes.. It working now.. Thanks